The Baselproblem from Euler
$Zeta(2) = 1/6 Pi^2$
This is the value of the Riemann Zeta function "for the number 2
Euler the famous mathematician first calculated this symbolic value in the 18 century in his "Basel problem.
Is it possible to derive this value also symbolically in Mathematica?
Note: there are several possible solutions and I want to look at the solution via the Taylor series development
(* Definieer de functie f(x) *)
f[x_] := Sin[x]/x

(* Taylorreeks van f(x) rond x = 0 *)
taylorSeries = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 3}] // Normal

(* Breid de Taylorreeks uit tot voldoende termen *)
taylorSeriesSum = Sum[((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(1 + 2 n), {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* Vergelijk met de Taylorreeks van f(x) *)
taylorSeries == taylorSeriesSum


There is missing factorial sign ! in your sum. It should be (1 + 2 n)!.

It is about comparing series expansion and product expansion of Sin[x]/x. The coefficient of x^2 in the series must coincide with coefficient of x^2 in the product (after expanding the product and collecting powers of x).

Product[(1 - x^2/(n^2 Pi^2)), {n, 1, ∞}] == 
  Sum[((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n + 1)!, {n, 0, ∞}] == Sin[x]/x // FullSimplify

Sum[(-(x^2/(n^2 Pi^2))), {n, 1, ∞}] == (((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n + 1)! /. n -> 1)

Sum[(-(x^2/(n^2 Pi^2))/(-(x^2/Pi^2))), {n, 1, ∞}] == ((((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n + 1)!)/(-(x^2/Pi^2)) /. n -> 1)

Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, ∞}] == ((((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n + 1)!)/(-(x^2/Pi^2)) /. n -> 1)

((((-1)^n x^(2 n))/(2 n + 1)!)/(-(x^2/Pi^2)) /. n -> 1)


True

True

True

True

Pi^2/6


Thanks , yes the proof idea is important
